# Django: Signal for "post initial migration"

Tags: django, django-signals

For setting up new development systems I would like to have a "post initial migration" signal.

It seems that something like this does not exist yet.

In detail: I want a signal which runs after the initial migrations have run. The second call to "manage.py migrate" should not emit this signal.

Use case: I want to set up basic data (add some users and groups, add some dummy data for "example.com", ...).

I don't want to use a migration for this, since in a migration I have only the limited model which gets returned by `apps.get_model("myapp", "Country")`.

Same for fixtures: I don't want to use fixtures because I get my tasks done much less painful if I have the real ORM model.

Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Can you explain more about the use case?

Comment: You mean some signal when make first migrations?

Comment: @AnshulSharma I updated my question. It contains a use case now.

Comment: @seuling I updated my question. Please tell me if there is something still not clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `post_migrate` signal. Check to see whether your dummy data has already been created (e.g. `if User.objects.exists():`) and stop if it does.

Comment: Yes, this is a pragmatic solution. Thank you

Comment: I use get_or_create() in a "post_migrate" signal handler now.

Answer (score 4):

@Alasdair's suggestion with the [`post-migrate` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-migrate) sounds good, but I'll add my two cents anyways.

In past situations where I needed initial data (for example a superuser and some base config data) I used a [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) to assure that some initial data was present. Fixtures were not exactly achieving what I needed in those situations.

This admin command has to be idempotent in the sense that it only makes changes if the desired state is not reached yet.

For example, my `ensure_auth_data` command looked something like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates superuser, permissions and groups.'

    def _ensure_superuser(self):
        u_created = False
        u_updated = False
        try:
            usr = User.objects.get(username='ralf')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            usr = User()
            usr.username = 'ralf'
            u_created = True

        if not usr.is_active:
            usr.is_active = True
            u_updated = True
        if not usr.is_superuser:
            usr.is_superuser = True
            u_updated = True

        if u_created or u_updated:
            usr.save()

        if u_created:
            self.stdout.write('Created superuser "{}"'.format(usr.username))
        elif u_updated:
            self.stdout.write('Updated superuser "{}"'.format(usr.username))
        else:
            self.stdout.write('Superuser "{}" already up to date'.format(usr.username))

    def _ensure_permissions(self):
        # create some special permissions if they're not present

    def _ensure_groups(self):
        # create some special groups and assign them permissions

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        self.stdout.write('Starting command')
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self._ensure_superuser()
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self._ensure_permissions()
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self._ensure_groups()
        self.stdout.write('...')
        self.stdout.write('Command finished')
```